# Where to find the manual for internal OpenCV functions starting with icv?

Tags: opencv

I would like to add a few functions to the OpenCV library for my own use. 
Here, it involves some internal functions starting with icv, for example, icvGetQuadrangleSubPix_8u32f_C1R.
I can guess that I should take a look for its description of GetQuadrangleSubPix(). But there are some additional parameters that are not mentioned in the user-accessible functions.

My question is where can I find the manual or description for this function? or what i should do is to trace back the parameters in that function.

Appreciate every answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: nowhere.. There were no any rules except that every internal function of OpenCV 1.x starts from "icv" prefix.

Comment: thanks - i just hope there existed.